# Flutter : A problem occurred configuring project ':speech_to_text'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, configuration, speech-to-text

I tried all possible way but didn't find how to configure " speech_to_text" in my existing flutter project.

Independent speech to text app working fine but i am not able to integrate in my existing app.

below steps i did still no luck   :

1. Internet and record audio permission in Android manifest.
2. adding latest dependencey  in pubspec.yaml speech_to_text
3. import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart' as stt;
4. stt.SpeechToText _speec  = stt.SpeechToText();
   5 . I change gradle version also which is same gradle version of woking "speech to text" app but independently

and i get below error

Log :
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':speech_to_text'.

> Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\jitkumar.gradle\caches\jars-8\c58c0f61a1162f88da75275a98d7f55b\auto-value-1.5.2.jar.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':speech_to_text' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Thanks